# Mjml image does not show up in my mail box in mobile

Tags: email, jinja2, mjml

I have to build a template to send for mail using `mjml` with `jinja2` template. I have inserted an image. After sending the mail the image only shows up in the Gmail web version, mobile version (Gmail app) the image can't load (it display a blue box with a question mark). I got the same problem with outlook. The image was stored in google photoes. I wonder why I have tried , the image inside raw with all attributes image as `background-url` inside a div but nothing worked for me!! How could I possibly encounter this issue?

```html
      <!--chart-->
      <mj-section border-left="solid 2px #bebebe" border-right="solid 2px #bebebe">
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text align="center">
            
            <!--Svg have not worked for me since it is not supported-->
            <!-- <mj-raw>
              <div class="chart flex col center">
                {{data.chart|safe}}
              </div>
            </mj-raw> -->

            <!-- mj-image does not display in mobil-->
            <!-- <mj-image align="center" src="{{data.chart}}" /> -->

             <!-- background URL also -->
            <mj-raw>
              <div class="chart flex col center" style="width: 100%; height:350px; display: block; background: url({{data.chart}}); background-size: contain; backgound-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: center;">
              </div>
            </mj-raw>

            <!-- Simple image also-->
            <!-- <mj-raw>
              <div class="chart flex col center">
                <img src={{data.chart}} width="200" alt="report" title="report" height="400px" style="display:block">
              </div>
            </mj-raw> -->

          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
      <!--/chart-->
```